# Understanding subclasses in python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and I have been watching some tutorials online because I want to work on a project using python open source library I found.

I know that it is possible to do inheritance in python like this

```
class Parent:
    def print(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def print(self):
        pass
```

However when i was looking at some code in my open source library I saw something like this.

```
from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.barfeed import yahoofeed


class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
        self.__instrument = instrument
```

Looking at this piece of code I am wondering what does `class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy)` imply. I would understand if it only said strategy in there because that would mean MyStrategy class is inherting from strategy. Also I do not understand what this line`strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)` is implying?

I would appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strategy` is the module you imported with:

```
from pyalgotrade import strategy
```

Now `strategy.BacktestingStrategy` is a class located inside the module `strategy`. This class will used as superclass for `MyStrategy`.

---

```
def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
    strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
    # ...
```

This function `__init__(self, feed, instrument)` is the constructor function of `MyStrategy` that will be called whenever you create a new instance of this class.

It overrides the `__init__` method of its superclass, but it still wants to also execute that old code. Therefore it calls its superclass' constructor method using

```
strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
```

In this line `strategy.BacktestingStrategy` is the superclass and `__init__` is its constructor method. You pass the argument `self` containing the current object instance as first argument explicitly, because the method gets called from the superclass directly and not from an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
strategy.BacktestingStrategy #this is the class that your MyStrategy class inherits , it is class BacktestingStrategy, located in strategy.py

strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)  # calls the parents constructor ... if the base class inherits from object you would typically do 

super().__init__(feed) # python 3 way of calling the super class
```

since strategy is a module (file/or in some cases folder) and not a class there is no way you could inherit from it ...